# Save bitmap to png in server from windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I have a function that has a bitmap instance in windows form application. I want this bitmap instance to be converted into png and save the png into given folder in server.

**Following is my piece of code:**

```
public void uploadLayerIcon()
{
    Bitmap icon = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\mun.jpg");
    icon.Save("http://192.168.1.30/muneem/erp/u.png",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

I am getting error invalid uri format.

How to upload this bitmap to server from windows form application?

Comment: The http protocol is not a filesystem uri. If you want to save to a server you would need to use filesystem or send the image via http to the server, where are that server? Do you have access to it?

Comment: yes i have access to these server

Comment: i just have only bitmap instance of image now how i convert this into png in server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

I convert bitmap image to base64encoded string and send that string to php script. Now php script decode that string and write content to file which is placed in the given location provided by user.

Comment: I'm glad you solve your problem, but... what you really needs from beginning was sending a file to a web application? Why don't you tell us this from beginning? We would help you better! Please, be more precise another time to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: thanks for your help i am not sending file i am sending bitmap string. I am extremely sorry i was not able to tell you clearly about my issue

Comment: No problem @MuneemHabib ! Just saying for another time, so you can get a precisily, faster and correct response ^^

Answer (score 2):

I just made a TestApplication to check, and the only thing is not working is just the URI of the destination. If you use something like this it should work:

```
icon.Save(@"\\192.168.1.30\muneem\erp\u.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: I have checked now i am getting an error occurded in GDI++

Comment: What error is showing you? I use for test one of the windows sample images (Chrysanthemum.jpg) and I had no problem.

Comment: i am getting error: A GENERIC ERROR OCCURED IN GDI+

Comment: Maybe it's a lack of permissions to write on that machine? Trying using you local ip address instead on the server. BTW I test this on a console application, I create a new Winforms proyect and test it, it keep working. I'm really convinced that it's a write permission issue.

Comment: i Have given full permission to all folders but still its not working i am getting error occured in GDI+

Comment: Commonly, that error could be triggered because three causes:
1) Lack of permissions to write. (The account executing the application of course)
2) The directory where you want to save don't exist.
3) The file exists and you try to overwrite it, but it is in use by another process.

Comment: can u help me by telling me how to upload simple png file to server?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to achieve sir! First of all, a few questions. 1) Do you check the three points on my previous comment? 2) What kind of server is? 3) Is UPLOAD or SAVING what you want?

Comment: Its not working thanks for help. I have apache server and i just want to save a png image in the location that i provide its not working with bitmap.save function. This function is for desktop use only